# Easy way to go back to the original "HEAD"

Tags: git

I have a git looking like following

```
A0 -- A1 -- ... -- An
```

`A0` is the newest commit. After lots of operations, including lots of resets, now I am in somewhere behind `A0`. Unfortunately I cannot remember exactly what is the commit id for `A0`. So how can I go back to `A0`?

Comment: does `git checkout HEAD` not work for you?

Comment: Is it a local history only or pulled from some another repository?

Comment: `git checkout branch_name`

Comment: Use some git history browsing application, e.g. `gitk`, to try and find out where you want to go. But doing resets and such *changes history*, so it is entirely possible that that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @vonbrand: reset moves the branch-to-which-`HEAD`-points, but the original values are kept in the reflog for at least 30 days by default.  They can be recovered during that period.  (It's often not much *fun* but it's good to know that they are available.)

Answer (score 0):

git has a command that will show you previous values of HEAD.  I think this should give you what you are looking for.

```
git reflog
```

Comment: You can read more about how to use `git reflog` from the [Data Recovery](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-7.html#Data-Recovery) section of the Pro Git book.

Answer (score 0):

{git reset --hard HEAD} would set the branch to A0. All changes done after the HEAD would be scrapped.